# Node.js/Vuetify- Is there a way to get data from server based on time?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a node.js server set up for a vuetify project. In my server, I am parsing a csv file that has information in it about scheduling and time. In my vuetify project, is there a way to get data from the csv based on the time that the client is being used?

Comment: Please, give an example.
The way I see it - you have time-based information in the CSV - 07:00 Breakfast; 08:00 Go to work; 12:00 Lunch break. And you want to get different results, based on the time of website access. So if I access it around 7, I will get back "Breakfast", if around 12, I will get back Lunch break.

Is that correct?

Comment: @IvanShulev that is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let's go with an example.

From what I understand, you have the following information in your CSV file:

```
Time,Activity
07:00,Breakfast
08:00,Go to work
12:00,Lunch break
```

Since you didn't specify, I will use an [example parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser), which will push all rows, as  objects, into an array:

```
[
   { Time: '07:00', Activity: 'Breakfast' },
   { Time: '08:00', Activity: 'Go to work' },
   { Time: '12:00', Activity: 'Lunch break' }
]
```

You need to send that information to your clients, so assuming you are using [Express](https://expressjs.com/), you could go with something in the lines of:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const timeSchedule = [];

function parseCsv() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (data) => timeSchedule.push(data))
        .on('error', (err) => reject(err))
        .on('end', () => {
            csvParsed = true;
            resolve();
        });
    }
}

app.get('/scheduled-for/:hour', function (req, res) {
    // You need to come up with the logic for your case
    // As an example, I will assume that if I make a request at any time
    // between 7 and 8, I will get "Breakfast"
    // between 8 and 9 - "Go to work"
    // between 12 and 13 - "Lunch break"
    parseCsv().then(() => {
        res.json(timeSchedule.find(row => row.Time.startsWith(req.params.hour)))
    })

})
```

Please note, *all of the above is happening on the Nodejs server.*

From the client, you will have to call the `scheduled-for` GET handle with the hour param. Another option is to allow the back-end to determine the hour of the request, by using the Date object, but the above is more flexible for the client. It will also avoid issues with different timezones, given that your client requests are coming from different timezones than the one your server is on.

Assuming you are using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) in your Vue application, the simplest way to get the schedule is to call your API in your component:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      activity: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://urlToYourApi/v1/scheduled-for/' + new Date().getHours())
      .then(schedule => {
          if (schedule) {
              this.activity = schedule.Activity;
          }
          else {
              console.log("No activity found for this hour!");
          }
      }
  }
})
```

This code is **NOT** for production! You need to handle many cases, as with `new Date().getHours()` returning single-digit hours, parsing of CSV, not to mention the domain logic itself, which depends on your specific case. This is just a simple example. I hope it helps to guide you in the right direction!